# How to extract pattern that begins and ends with specific word and does not contain specific word

Tags: sed, grep

I have already searched, but I haven't found anything fit for my purpose.

This is my pattern of data:

```
query=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbacteriaxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

query=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
@yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

query=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzbacteriazzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zbacteriazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
@zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

.
.
.
```

The pattern that I need to grab is

```
query=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
@
```

or

```
query=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
@yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

I know that `sed -n '/Query=/,/@/p'` should grab this pattern, but how can I exclude the pattern with the word `bacteria` inside.?

edit: I am so sorry to make you confused with my question. I provided you a new example.

edit2: I edited pattern that I need again. terribly sorry.

> THIS WORKS `sed '/query/!d;{:a;N;/@/!ba;/bacteria/d;s/@.*/@/}' infile`
>   thank to ctac_

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. please post some simplified patterns that you want to match/reject.

Comment: How can the pattern you need to grab contain something that apparently is not in the input data? Or maybe I don't understand the meaning of the two pieces of data.

Comment: Please improve your question. It's not clear what you want. It would be helpful some examples too

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Poz '^query=.*(\n.*?)*bacteria.*(\n.*?)*.*@.*' file`

Comment: I think this is what OP is looking for: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228699/sed-print-lines-matched-by-a-pattern-range-if-one-line-matches-a-condition

Comment: I need to reject word `bacteria` in my result. sorry to make you confused.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/query/{:a;N;/@/!ba;/bacteria/!p}' file
```

Turn on seds grep-like nature using `-n`. Find `query` and then append more lines until one containing `@`. Search those lines for `bacteria` and if not  found print them.

This solution is a multiline solution where there will always two or more lines. For a solution to include one or more, use:

```
sed -n '/query/{:a;/@/!{N;ba};/bacteria/!p}' file
```

Comment: I tried it but `bacteria` is still present in the result. I need to reject pattern that contain `bacteria`. Could you give me other suggestion? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed

```
sed '/^query/!d;:A;N;/\n$/!{$!bA};h;s/bacteria//;tB;x;b;:B;d' infile
```

Comment: ahhh It's my fault again. I was in hurry to edit without checking. The last word in my expected result in each pattern should stop at `@` or at the line that contain `@` is fine. I am appreciate your help.

Comment: @ChooseelBunsuwansakul you must update your question

Comment: potong answer is the best answer. you must add ! before p. If you want to keep only @ at the end, you can try sed '/query/!d;{:a;N;/@/!ba;/bacteria/d;s/@.*/@/}' infile

Comment: your code work! MILLION THANKS `sed '/query/!d;{:a;N;/@/!ba;/bacteria/d;s/@.*/@/}' infile`